# Cannot change region because cannot delete payment method because have active subscriptions

Tags: icloud, apple-id

You are my only hope as I am desperate!

I have moved to a new country, so my old country bank card is now closed. To this card my AppleID is still linked but now it indicates that I must update payment method information. Naturally, the card is closed so a new one has to be given to Apple.

That’s what I thought when leaving for a new place: I will add a new card, so Apple could see I have a new land/region card and phone number, once it is accepted, I will be able to change my land/region in the AppleID account settings, and after that I thought, I would be able to safely delete the obsolete old card and all my subscriptions and purchases would seamlessly be transferred to a new card, so any new monthly/yearly subscriptions would be charged from the new card. That was the plan, since that is the only natural way of things I could imagine!

Yet Apple decided to do it painfully. I discovered that I only can add a new card from the same old land/region to which my old card also assigned. It won’t allow me to add a card from any other land/region! So, I first need to delete the old card. But I cannot do it either, as there is no “None” option in the list of the payment options. I was notified that I only can do that if there is no active AppleTV subscriptions, iTunes subscriptions etc., unpaid debts,pending charges, etc.

Looks reasonable, I thought, so no one could escape old land/region with Apple money. So I had two pending payments: one from AppleMusic, one from iCloud disk extra storage service. I could not fulfill the charges from my old card, so I purchased AppleGift card from the same old region/land and used it to charge up my AppleID.

A remarkably wonderful detail: Apple took the money for these two payments when I manually pressed “Pay” it attempted to charge my old card, was rejected naturally, pop-up error message box, but after that decided that to take money from AppleID is better than not to take at all)))

So, it took my money from AppleID, but ... IT DID NOT UPDATE THE SERVICES! It did not add a month to Apple Music and it still on free (5Gb) plan for my Apple Storage which is normally 200 Gb (although it shows it is 200 Gb, only 3 Gb is available with 47Gb used... I don’t know how to interpret this!)

I cannot upload big files to iCloud storage so I concluded that it did not update the service plan; andirons complains every time I open AppleMusic that a problem is occurred with payment method, so I assume that none of the two services were updated, but money was charged!

Okay, forget it Apple. I manually cancelled regularly occurring subscription payments on the list, including the two services. But AppleTV will be active albeit not automatically renewed, for a month, and some other yearly subscriptions will only expire in a just below a whole year!

On the Apple support page they say that I will be able to remove the payment method when eventually all active subscription will expire, including AppleTV, AppleMusic and any iTunes staff.

Now, that’s a long time to wait! Does that really means what it sound? I am so desperate that I am okay to deny my active subscriptions all together, just to set it free and be able to delete the obsolete payment method and add a new payment method according to my new land/region.

Maybe you know some exotic way to make it happen without waiting for every single subscription to expire?

Thank you for every your thought and suggestion,
Take care!

UPD1: Actually Apple says explicitly here that AppleID credit may be used to pay for iCloud storage and Apple Music, App,eTV+ and other Apple services:

https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/HT201209

OBS: NO REGIONAL RESTRICTIONS ARE MENTIONED!

In my observation, however, this only is allowed for iTunes Films, Music, and one-time purchases from AppStore. No subscriptions, Albeith for Apple services, or third-party in-app purchases, are possible in this setup (when the primary payment method is failing).

Thus, if one wants to use any services or app on subscription, one might do either of two things: 1) restore access to the old payment method (impossible in my case) 2) delete the old payment method (also impossible, until every active subscription is expired which would take a year for me).

So does that mean that for a year my iDevices are jailed on quarantine together with me, and there is nothing I can do, no way to forcedly deny active subscriptions, to interrupt them immediately, even at cost of loosing services, just to set the AppleID free at last and make it happen?!

Sergio

Comment: If you have moved from the US, it could be possible to go on with iTunes gift cards that you can purchase off of the internet until your longest-serving subscription expires.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had a hope I could do just that, and that I tried twice. I purchased iTunes and AppStore Gift cards, so I can now buy films, songs and apps, but NOT the subscriptions, meaning that I am disconnected from Apple Music, iCloud storage and any monthly subscriptions until the very latest of the yearly subscription expires! Sounds a torture!

Comment: Are u sure about the subscriptions? I have a US account and I had been paying for my iCloud subscription with the credit I had put on my Apple ID account using iTunes gift cards until quite recently. From what I can see through [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631), this is still possible.